# Links on top of elements with onclick-handlers

Tags: javascript, html

Hey. I've got a dumb, but nasty problem.

If I've got this (simplified) situation:

```
<div onclick="doSomething(); return false;">
    lorem ipsum <a href="somewhere.html">dolor sit</a> amet
</div>
```

...is there any (convenient) way to prevent the onclick-handler of the parent div from being triggered when the link is clicked.

In my scenario, I've got a big wrapping div that is made into a "link" with an onclick-handler, but I'd like to overlay some text data with links in it, but at least in Firefox when I click on the links in the text, the onclick of the parent is executed first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get around this by testing the original target of the event in your handler. Something along the lines of:

```
function doSomething ( e ) {
  // get event object and target element
  var e = e || window.event;
  var target = e.srcElement || e.target;
  // is target a div?
  if ( target && /^div$/i.test( target.nodeName ) ) {

    // do your magic in here ...

  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With jQuery you can add a click handler to each of your anchors and use [event.stopPropagation()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.stopPropagation.28.29) to keep the event from bubbling up to the DIV.

```
   $('div#wrapperDiv > a').click( function(event) {
       event.stopPropagation();
   });
```

Comment: event bubbling is the problem - http://www.brainjar.com/dhtml/events/default2.asp

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, this is a bad nesting of HTML/behavior.  Either the whole div is clickable as 1 element, or the link is, but not both... unless you "un-nest" them.

Comment: I think the OP recognizes this (cf "dumb...problem").